# Differece between Strike Arrest and Quata policies

Tags: apigee

I am new to Apigee Service.
I was using certain policies provided by Apigee.
What is the difference between Strike Arrest policy and Quota policy used in APIGEE edge??

Comment: does strike arrest policy apply to specific API or on set of APIs??

Answer (score 0):

Spike Arrest Policy - This policy is helpful to control concurrency or rate of message flow. Spike arrest is not meant to control traffic from a specific consumer, it is meant to limit overall rate or burst of traffic.

Quota Policy - Quota policy is useful to control traffic from a given consumer. Quota can be set per consumer, hence restricting a specific consumer from overusing than its allocated quota.

Spike arrest counter is not distribute, hence spike arrest work per node and in disconnected way (analogy would be each node has its own isolated check).

Quota counter is distributed, hence it works in a connected way ( analogy would be common synchronized counter for all nodes).

These two policy are recommended to be used in Proxy-Request flow, so that traffic throttling or restrictions can be enabled at beginning of Api-proxy flow.